# NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification isn't triggered from extension

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to observe the `NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification` from my application. What I want is when a `UserDefaults` is set from my keyboard extension that the application should trigger on that change.

The `UserDefaults` works to share values between the extension and the app. But how do I set it up so that the application listens for changes?

The purpose of the notification and shared data is to see if the user has allowed full access for the keyboard. If not, then I want to display some instructions on how to turn it on. If you have any other ideas on how I could solve this are more than welcome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, your app and its extensions have no direct access to each other’s data.

If you want your app and its extensions to be able to share data, use Xcode or the Developer portal to enable app groups for the app and its extensions. Next, register the app group in the portal and specify the app group to use in the your app.

For more Information you can refer this link:- http://www.tekramer.com/sharing-data-between-apps-extensions/